# How do I make a factory that creates random titles without a dot at the end?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am working on a Laravel 8 **blogging application**. I need a large numer of articles in order to test the pagination.

For this purpose, I have made this factory:

```
class ArticleFactory extends Factory
{ 
 /**
 * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $model = Article::class;

/**
 * Define the model's default state.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function definition()
{
    
    $title = $this->faker->sentence(2);

    return [
          'user_id' => $this->faker->randomElement([1, 2]),
          'category_id' => 1,
          'title' => $title,
          'slug' => Str::slug($title, '-'),
          'short_description' => $this->faker->paragraph(1),
          'content' => $this->faker->paragraph(5),
          'featured' => 0,
          'image' => 'default.jpg',
    ];
  }
}
```

#### The problem

Unfortunately, the `title` column in the `articles` table is populated with sentences that have a dot at the end. Titles are **not** supposed to end with a dot.

###### How can I fix this?

Comment: For your use case i don't see a reason why you couldn't just do `$title = $this->faker->name()`

Comment: Well `name()` returns a name, and to get the fake data to be as true to life as possible it would make sense to provide something other than a name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `$this->faker->sentence(2);` you could use `$this->faker->words(3, true);` where you can replace the `3` with the amount of words you want. `true` is there so it returns a string and not an array

It adds a dot because you use `->sentence()` and sentences, normally, have a period at the end. Whereas words typically do not have a period at the end.

You can ofcourse also provide a random amount of words by using `rand()`. Say you want a title to be between 5 and 15 words, you can use `$this->faker->words(rand(5, 15), true);`

Comment: or remove the dot without asking too many questions: `$title = rtrim($title, ".");`

Comment: How about a random number of words?

Comment: @DiegoDeVita Sure, that's an option aswell.

Comment: If one would choose to generate words, then I recommend wrapping that in `ucfirst` to make the first letter uppercase, just like that: `ucfirst($this->faker->words(rand(5, 15), true))`

Answer (score 1):

This is how I choose to achieve the desired result, in case it helps someone else:

```
public function definition() {
        
  $title = $this->faker->sentence(2);

  return [
    'user_id' => $this->faker->randomElement([1, 2]),
    'category_id' => 1,
    'title' => rtrim($title, '.'),
    'slug' => Str::slug($title, '-'),
    'short_description' => $this->faker->paragraph(1),
    'content' => $this->faker->paragraph(5),
    'featured' => 0,
    'image' => 'default.jpg',
   ];
}
```